# UIWebView crash with Assertion failed: (addr != MAP_FAILED), function _open_and_mmap_for_reading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have an app with an embedded `UIWebView`. When I load a specific page into it, it crashes the simulator without an exception, but I see the following message in the Xcode console:

> Assertion failed: (addr != MAP_FAILED), function
>   _open_and_mmap_for_reading, file /SourceCache/LanguageIdentifier_Sim/LanguageIdentifier-114/LanguageIdentifier.c,
>   line 593.

Sometimes, I see the following message in my console instead:

> malloc: *** mmap(size=2097152) failed (error code=12)

This crash occurs in a background thread:

```
Thread 20, Queue : com.apple.root.default-priority
#0  0x93c4ea6a in __pthread_kill ()
#21 0x92138e72 in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

I don't think this is a memory leak of mine.  This crashes in iOS6, iOS6.1, and iOS7 in both the simulator and device. I never see any messages in the console when the device crashes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular HTML had a table with the following style:

```
width="393025px"
```

When I called the following line:

```
CGSize fitsSize = [self.webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

I got a crazy-wide size: (width=393158, height=2763), which I promptly set my `UIWebView`'s size to:

```
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, fitsSize.width, fitsSize.height)
```

Obviously, this is bad. `UIWebView` can't handle being that big.

Changing my resize code to

```
self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), fitsSize.height)
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: That height is super tall.  Is your web view in a scroll view?  It's a little verbose but I like to do `CGRect frame = self.webView.frame; frame.size.height = fitsSize.height; self.webView.frame = frame;` That way you're only modifying the dimension of interest.

Comment: Yes, the `UIWebView` is in a `UIScrollView` (which is itself in a `UITableView.headerView`). I suppose it might be worth filing a radar about this.

Comment: In that case, why not just ditch the scroll view and depend on the web view's built in scroll view?

Comment: Because I want the contents of the `UITableView` to scroll seamlessly below the `UIWebView`.